# How to protect or hide oAuth CLIENT_SECRET using Javascript in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, salesforce

Hi I am developing a chrome extension to perform oAuth2 with Salesforce. I would like to know what is the best alternative way to secure the client secret which is stored at client side using js. I have already gone through many articles which state to use a server to store the values. But I would like to know whether there are any other ways and if someone has successfully solved this issue. I am currently following oAuth for non-google providers as given in https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity. I am somewhat a newbie and would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [User-Agent OAuth Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_user_agent_oauth_flow.htm) you shouldn't need to put the client secret in the code base.

Comment: Thank you. The solution was much appreciated